# Insertar datos en MySQL leyendo .CSV desde Python

Tags: mysql, python, phpmyadmin, csv, python-3.7

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy intentando insertar los datos de un archivo.csv a mi base de datos. He hecho la sentencia SQL desde mi PhpMyAdmin e inserta los datos correctamente asi que creo que el error lo tengo en el Python y no consigo detectarlo

Código Python:

```
os.system('cls')
    print("Quin nom tindra el questionari?")
    taula=input()#Leer nombre de tabla a crear
    crearTaula(taula)#Crea tabla pedida

    with open('prova.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO '+taula+' (Pregunta,Resposta,Puntuacio) VALUES( '+row[0]+', '+row[1]+', 25)')
    csvFile.close()
    TancarPrograma()#una vez insertados datos pide si quieres cerrrar el programa
```

Archivo prova.csv:

```
1+1?,2
2+2?,4
3+3?,6
4+4?,8
```

Una vez creada la tabla en Numero="AutoIncremento", en "Pregunta y Resposta" quiero que sea los valores del .csv y en "Puntuacio" que siempre sea 25
[image: Esta es la tabla una vez creada]

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Desde mi desconocimiento de Python, a primera vista creo que comentes un error al crear la sentencia sql. Los campos Pregunta y Resposta son varchar, por lo que al hacer el insert, los valores deberían estar entre comillas simples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera en la inserción:

```
with open('prova.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO "+taula+" (pregunta,resposta,puntuacio) VALUES (%s, %s, 25)",
            (str(row[0]), str(row[1]))
        )
csvFile.close()
```